# How to force custom Magento REST services to be accessed through HTTPS?

Tags: rest, magento

I have been working on Magento for a couple of weeks and have learned how to write custom REST services successfully. My problem is that I need to make them available only through HTTPS. For example, if the URI is something like:

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento/api/rest/v1/stores
```

I want to make it only accessible at:

```
https://127.0.0.1/magento/api/rest/v1/stores
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect this is not a Magento question but a webserver configuration issue. Which webserver are you running it on (Apache, IIS, ...) ?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is purely related to Magento. Magento offers ways to make custom module where one can write their own controller, routers, rest services etc. Also it provides a way to make certain URL be accessed in a secure way using https. In my case I have developed a custom rest services but I don't know how to secure that URI

Comment: No problem, just came across this post from the review queue - I don't know anything about Magento. Was just wondering whether to add a web server tag, to attract a different audience.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to set [controller routes to be secure in your extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/37722/20131) is in its `config.xml`. So in your case it would probably be something like this:

```
<frontend>
    <secure_url>
        <magento_api_rest>/magento/api/rest</magento_api_rest>
    </secure_url>
</frontend>
```